# Aptana , working with friends localhost

Tags: localhost, aptana

With Aptana Studio, is it possible to work with friends on localhost? 
I want to add my friends to my project, everybody should able to edit and commit changes.
And revision control if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but everything deserves an answer right?

Localhost is your computer, if your friends should access Localhost on their computer they would see just that, their own computer, not yours.

You could set up your Localhost to accept connections from outside your computer but they would have to access it not as Localhost, but as the ip or DNS.

If you want version control and all that stuff you could use Git for instance and then everyone would be able to push and pull and still have a local repro on their own localhost but use git to maintain the code accross different computers and localhost. Github is a good place to start if you want to add friends to a project.